# Asking about Navigate coursebook of The Oxford University Press

Tags: meaning, books

I got 2 coursebooks of Navigate books bellow, I realize that the content of the two coursebook is different. 
My question is that why are there difference between those coursebooks? Does that mean that the "Teacher's edition" just uses in classroom and has to study with teacher, right?

[image]

Comment: Uh, the one on the right is "elementary", while the one on the left is "intermediate" -- different educational levels.

Comment: @HotLicks: ignore levels for those coursebooks, what does "teacher's edition" mean, please?

Comment: "Teacher's edition" would be one with answers to quiz questions, additional commentary on some points in the book, etc.